# "Free-available" universities beyond Russia.

Tags: soft-question

There is an absolutely amazing place in Moscow where **anyone** can listen to lectures in Russian, discuss math in Russian and, eventually, try to pass exams (of course in Russian).

What makes it  rather interesting  is that one doesn't even need to have a student ID or something like that — entrance is always free! I mean [The Independent University of Moscow](http://ium.mccme.ru/english/).

I  want  to know  in which countries, if any, there exist other similar universities with "free access".
I'm especially interested in English-speaking countries.

Comment: You wont find that russian - communist thing in America or in an western country.  In my university, I dont think they will kick you out for sitting in lecture or even notice but you gotta pay at the end of the day.  have you look at open courses online? there is a course in linear algebra by gilbert strang  his textbook is a bit pricy. (There are also aton  of old versions of books that are work less than the shipping 5$). It seems you want to interact with math teachers

Comment: This might be better suited for Academia SE

Comment: @Iloveass2 I'm going to visit an English-speaking country in order to improve my English, as well as mathematical English. I shall be glad if I attend maths lectures.

Comment: If you have not taken linear algebra, Gilbert strang has youtube videos  and he is a sweatheart and would be a good way to improve your english. Its a start.

Answer (score 1):

While not english-speaking, in France you can do part of that.

**Universities**

On principle, Universities are open to everyone. You have the "right" to assist to any course any time you want. Specific sessions with TA are restricted however to people enlisted.

In practice, there are access restriction in some cases, like entering the buildings or premises. It may require to state your case and desire to be granted access, and pass through the control (and the people enforcing it might not be aware of this "fundamental" right). This is usually easier in early years of teaching, with very large attendance, that it is with classes of a dozen people all on the teacher attendance list.

**Collège de France**

This is an institution whose purpose is both research and teaching at very high level. You can assist lectures freely (sometimes you need to register yourself in advance). However the topics are not following the flow of a course, and can be on any subject, so you can't rely on it to build your knowledge logically and reliably. This is for cherry picking!

**PHD lectures**

Like all "exams" in France, you have the right to assist to it if you don't disrupt. It is, of course, very specific and very much like lecture at the Collège de France.

**Caveats and workarounds**

With all of the above, you can't take exams. Exams are restricted to people enlisted in the Universities.

However, in France Universities fees are usually fairly small (a few hundreds euros per year for most Universities), and there is no age restriction.

There might be restriction based on: (i) level (you need to have initial years passed - or equivalent level - before taking more advanced courses) or (ii) number of people wanting to take the class (more a local problem for some specific courses, and usually only for first and second year of University)

For English courses, I will let the Americans, British, Irish, Scottish, Welsh, Australians... speak for it!

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. The "right" to attend any lecture you want in any university you want does not exist. As you say, merely entering the university requires to have some kind of student ID. It's possible that the lecturer will tolerate your presence or not notice that you're not of the usual students, but this isn't a "right" to attend the lecture -- you can get kicked out, and if you are you have no recourse.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi This right does exist. Now it is kind of restricted through the invention of the "auditeur libre" status, that you can get and that gives you a student ID card, and it costs between 40 and 140€ per year depending on the universities.

Comment: So it's not something that you're entitled to. It's something you need to apply and pay for. That's completely different.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi To be honest this is something that we were entilted to, and that disappeared as such with the invention of auditeur libre status. The main reason for the auditeur libre is for the responsability in case of any issues on the premise of the university.